# show and hide toTopButton according the scrolling but window.onscroll not work ..i can not fix the real problem

Tags: javascript, css

Please I need your support as I write this code to create a button and when I press it I move to the top of page ...the button is created good and move to top of page ... But I want the button hide when the scrolling in the top of page and appear again when I scroll down ...the scroll function not work I do not know the reason … I support you with the code in JavaScript and CSS related to my question …you are genius if you can fix it.

First JavaScript code

```
//here i create a function to make scroll smooth...i can write it in css file but i want to show what is i lrarned:
const scrollSmoothly = function () {
  const myHTML = document.querySelector("html");
  myHTML.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
};

//create the to Top Button
//
scrollSmoothly();
function toTopButton_create() {
  const toTopButton = document.createElement("botton");
  const textnodeTOP = document.createTextNode("TO_Top");
  toTopButton.appendChild(textnodeTOP);
  //document.querySelector("footer").appendChild(toTopButton);
  const rr = document.querySelector("footer");
  rr.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", toTopButton);

  toTopButton.setAttribute("id", "ourBtn");
  toTopButton.addEventListener("click", test2);
}
toTopButton_create();

//below function to go to the top of sheet
function test2() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

// below function to hide the (to top button) in the top and appear again when we scroll down

window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    toTopButton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    toTopButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**CSS code**

```
#ourBtn {
  padding: 16px;
  right: 31px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  z-index: 98;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(17, 199, 231);
  color: rgb(29, 2, 2);
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ourBtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(219, 8, 8);
}
```

Note : when I change in CSS code and make  `display: none;` the button hidden and when I change it to `display: block;` it appear again …this is not problem ...the real problem that the (to top button) not appear and hidden according  to the scrolling ... I think the scroll function not work. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to add some HTML and modify a bit your question to make a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you may will get better answers

Answer (score 0):

#### Change this part of your code

```js
// below function to hide the (to top button) in the top and appear again when we scroll down

window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    toTopButton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    toTopButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

#### To this

```js
// below function to hide the (to top button) in the top and appear again when we scroll down

document.onscroll = scrollFunction;

function scrollFunction(event) {
  if (event.srcElement.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    toTopButton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    toTopButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Note:

- Attach the event to the document object
- Look for the `scrollingElement` (it might not be the `body` element)

Comment: it still not work, although I put your suggestioned code

Comment: Inside the `scrollFunction`, can you add a `console.log(event)` and inspect the 'event' data? Just to be sure if the scroll event fired

Comment: The main problem in my code was the variable (toTopButton) this variable defined in the function ,so it is not declared out it ...when I create it a gain in the global area the function work good .....now it works good.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in my code was the variable (toTopButton) this variable defined in the function ,so it is not declared or defined  out the function  ...when I create it a gain in the global area ...the function worked good

Comment: Another member posted a viable answer.
This answer seems to have been shared and the path proposed makes sense, I would suggest for you to give the suggestions a chance, you might learn some more!
If you really want to answer your own question it could be helpful to highlight in more detail what the changes are that you have taken.